# three js change radius of sphere with dat gui?

Tags: three.js, webgl

http://mrtn.ch/3D/13_06_27_gui_03.html

started analysing example files and now I'm wondering how to properly adress the radius of my sphere with the dat gui slider. I can move the slider but the sphere keeps the initial radius. What's wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: link is 404, please update eventually

Answer (score 10):

SphereGeometry only uses the radius parameter when it is created. There's no built-in way to change it afterwards. You need to manually modify the geometry vertices, or create a new SphereGeometry with the new radius.

Alternatively, you can just scale the sphere. In your updatesphere() function, try something like:

```
radius = parameters.radius;
var scale = radius * 0.1; // adjust the multiplier to whatever
sphere.scale.setScalar(scale);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I already managed to use the scale function but that doesn't really solve the problem of changing the amount of segments on my sphere. I was hoping for an easy solution, too bad....